# IntelliJ IDEA / RubyMine inserting hex characters in Find in Path field

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

I currently have a small problem with my editor. Whenever I try "Find in Path" my computer automatically pastes in the following: "YYYY DDDD YYYY YYYY YYYY >>>> YYYY FFFF XXXX XXXX"

I don't know why it happens all at once because it wasn't always like that.

Does anyone happen to know why all this is happening to me and maybe how I can solve it? Of course I can do CMD + A & CMD + V to avoid the problem, but not permanently.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by the [GPG Services](https://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/87979-gpg-keychain-shortcut-key-combination-really-anoying). See also [IDEA-201301](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201301).

Reply from the GPG Services team:

> While we have fixed this problem in our code already, you will unfortunately have to disable the shortcuts manually in **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** (look for any `OpenPGP:` entry).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Didn’t knew this was a thing.